# How to diagnose three simultaneous downvotes on my answers?

Tags: support, serial-voting

I just got 3 simultaneous downvotes on my answers; this seems like an impossible coincidence.

```
-2  01:41  downvote  SSH fingerprint verification for Amazon AWS EC2 server with ECDSA?
-2  01:40  downvote  Ruby “gem generate” indexer broken with XML Builder 3.0.0. How to fix?
-2  01:40  downvote  Ruby “gem generate” indexer broken with XML Builder 3.0.0. How to fix?
```

Does SO have any way to diagnose what happened? For example, does SO have any way to see if there's any relation among these 3?

Comment: Seriously, you probably don't want to get too concerned about three downvotes, however oddly timed. Downvotes happen. I wouldn't bother to bother for less than 10 suspicious votes.

Comment: @bmargulies Good point. This is the first time I've seen this on SO, and it came right after I gave a bounty, so it's curious to me.

Answer (score 7):

The system checks for suspicious voting patterns periodically, and if it does happen to find a pattern, it may invalidate those votes where appropriate. When votes cast on your posts are removed they will appear in your reputation history labeled "Serial downvoting reversed".

Moderators have tools to identify voting patterns but only when cast in significant volumes. We cannot link individual votes to users, as votes are anonymous by design, but when patterns arise we can investigate and handle them accordingly.

If the downvotes remain on your posts after 24 hours, feel free to flag one of them for moderator attention and we'll look into it.

See also: [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

Comment: If you have very few downvotes on your posts in general, are moderators able to see patterns from these votes or is this based on having an large amount of votes in absolute terms?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy: Any answer to your question would divulge too many details about SE voter fraud detection, and make it more susceptible to gaming.